# TextBox causes listview load items with a delay

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making an application based around a treeview, when I click the items in the treeview a listview will display the properties of that item like a propertygrid for editing.  When i have a small number of items it loads up very quickly, before i have finished my click, but when have around 20 items there is a noticeable delay.  I have tried to replicate the issue in the code below, the delay isnt as big as my main program but it is noticeable.

The below code demonstrates the delay in loading the view when one item with 26 TextBoxes is clicked.  This problem does not exist if you replace the textbox in the datatemplate with a textblock.

```
public class Items : INPCBase
{
    public Items()
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItemViewModel> { };
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
        Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count }); 
    }

    void vm_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            foreach (var vm in vms)
                Rows.Remove(vm);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var vm in vms)
                Rows.Add(vm);
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemViewModel> Rows { get; private set; } 

}

  public class Items1 : INPCBase
  {
   public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemViewModel> Rows { get; private set; } 
   public Items1()
   {

       Rows = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItemViewModel> { };
       Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
       Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
       Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
       Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
       Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
       Rows.Add(new ListViewItemViewModel() { Data = Rows.Count });
   }
}
public class ListViewItemViewModel : INPCBase
{
    public ListViewItemViewModel()
    {
        Group = 1;
        Title = "Name";
        Data = "temp";
        HorizontalDataAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public HorizontalAlignment HorizontalDataAlignment { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> Columns { get; set; }


   }
}
```

and the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyList" Source="{Binding Rows}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ListViewItemViewModel}">
            <Grid Height="25">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="1"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Data}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalDataAlignment}" Margin="4,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}" Grid.Column="2" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid >
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ColumnDescriptor}">
            <Grid  >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition  SharedSizeGroup="{Binding SharedSizeGroup}"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding DisplayObject}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0"/>
            </Grid >
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>


    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Margin="10" FontSize="12" ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" local:GridViewColumnResize.Enabled="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

            <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <x:Static Member="GroupStyle.Default"/>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Properties\DataTypeResources.xaml"/>
            </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,10,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,10,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button2_Click" />
</Grid>
```

can anyone tell me why the textbox causes this delay and how I could fix it.  Thanks.

---

I understand that INPC isnt implement correctly and I also understand that I should have a strongly typed data instead of object.  This is just a rough example, the issue isnt the binding the issue is displaying 20+ textboxes in a short period of time.  You can remove all the binding and only display the textboxes and it has the same effect.  How can i speed up the loading of the textboxes?

Comment: My first suggestion to you would be for you to learn how to correctly implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Comment: `public object Data { get; set; }` - Wrong. Use a strongly typed item instead of `object`.

Comment: please see my updated queston

Answer (score 0):

I had my computer on power saver as soon as I changed it to balanced the delay want noticed.  was still hoping to improve the speed but havent got any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The delay you notice has one of its roots in the fact that you are using the GUI thread to do the loading. Try loading the items asynchronously and not on the GUI thread. Such as this example here

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
               Items1();
            });
```

I have a full example on my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

The other situation is that you are loading all items and using a control which would page the items as needed. I would use a control which can handle such paging instead.